# htaccess RewriteRule to new domain keeping query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have found help regarding this in other questions and answers but they do not specifically address what I am trying to do.

My RewriteRules look like this...

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/rd/r.php? [QSA]
```

I need http://domain.com/query.php?sid=1234&pub=123456&c1=will&c2=test1&c3=12345 to redirect to http://newdomain.com/rd/r.php?sid=1234&pub=123456&c1=will&c2=test1&c3=12345

many thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the current behavior (please post an example URL and what it is currently redirecting to)? Remove the `?` at the end of the rule - that removes the query string. The [QSA] should not be necessary at that point.

Comment: changed it to...
  
`#Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.allsystemsarego.info$[OR]  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^allsystemsarego.info$  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ affiliate.gwmtracker.com/rd/r.php`  

The result on the receiving end is that we get the referrer but not the parameters.

Comment: how do you line break in a comment here? Two spaces does not work.

Comment: It's generally easiest to add any code as an edit to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?allsystemsarego.info$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://affiliate.gwmtracker.com/rd/r.php?%1 [R,L]
```

The query string is supposed to pass through untouched, but if it isn't you can explicitly grab it as above. The `%1` is a backreference to the match from the first `RewriteCond`, containing the query string.

I simplified your original two RewriteConds into one by matching with or without the leading `www.` via the `(www.)?` portion of the rule.

Comment: That stripped the query string completely. What if I use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?allsystemsarego.info/query.php$` the actual url I want to use is `http://allsystemsarego.info/query.php?sid=4980&pub=201257&c1=abc&c2=321&c3=123` which should redirect to `http://affiliate.gwmtracker.com/rd/r.php?sid=4980&pub=201258&c1=abc&c2=321&c3=123`

Comment: The `%{HTTP_HOST}` only matches against the domain name. If you only want to match query.php and not anything else on the site, the final RewriteRule pattern would change from `^(.*)$` to `^query.php$`. When you say, "That stripped the query string completely," do you mean that it wasn't fully stripped before? (I thought that's what you implied.) If the redirect part is working, the query string should be coming with it ... is it just redirecting to `/rd/r.php`?

Comment: I see and I get it now, and it worked. One last thing, if I want to not include the sid=4980 in the originating URL but rewrite the url with sid=4980 in the string, how can it be done?

Comment: Just add `sid=4980&` before the `%1`. That's if you will never include it in the original. If it might be there sometimes, you'll need to add logic to check for it and only add it if it isn't already there.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked. All props to [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1971315/david-ravetti)!David Ravetti.

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^query.php$ http://newdomain.com/subdir/file.php?pub=123456 [L,QSA]
```